# Book or a source to study time series analysis

Tags: time-series

Can anyone plz suggest me a book for time series analysis. I am a beginner in this topic, but there is a course in my college and for that I need a book which gives all information in detail. I am doing major in business and studying time series in a course named Business Analytics Models. There is a brief topic of time series in course, but I've realised that this topic cannot be studied in short. So plz suggest a book or a lecture series for this.
I have intermediate knowledge of statistics and mathematics.

Comment: What do you mean by intermediate knowledge of statistics and mathematics? how well you know probability theory and inference?